# Objective-C preprocessor directive issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have implemented this code for defining my constants:

```
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
#define IS_IPAD() (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#else
#define IS_IPAD() (false)
#endif

#if (IS_IPAD)
CGFloat const scrollSizeWidth = 768.0f;
CGFloat const scrollSizeHeight = 1004.0f;
#else
CGFloat const scrollSizeWidth = 320.0f;
CGFloat const scrollSizeHeight = 460.0f;
#endif
```

But it always display **320.0f** and **460.0f** for my variables.

**UPDATE:**
As k3a user found UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM does not work for iOS 8.3, because it's not longer a define it's a static inline.

Check this answer as well:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608613/how-can-i-detect-if-device-is-an-ipad-in-ios-8-2-3-xcode-6-3)

Comment: #ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is broken in Xcode 6.3+ as it is no longer a preprocessor define

Comment: @k3a oh shooot, really? I've not checked it yet

Comment: Yup. I've noticed it as my app loaded iPhone nibs when compiled with Xcode 6.3+. Here is the new definition of that symbol:    static inline UIUserInterfaceIdiom UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() {
    return ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] ?
            [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] :
            UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone);
}

Comment: @k3a yeah I think the solution we can use [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)

Comment: yep, but the original code part "#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM" now doesn't work as UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is not a define but a function instead ;) mentioned it so the people know...

Comment: @k3a, yea added it as an update, if some one check my question, I think it will be helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
#define IS_IPAD() (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#else
#define IS_IPAD() (false)
#endif
```

to

```
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#else
#define IS_IPAD (false)
#endif
```

Comment: sorry its work but now I get just 768.0f 1004.0f; I mean at any time

Answer (score 2):

If `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` is not a preprocessor symbol, then it can't be used in preprocessor conditionals.