# How can I detect if device is an iPad in iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios8.3

We updated our SDK to iOS 8.3, and all of a sudden, our iPad detection method doesn't work properly:

```
+ (BOOL) isiPad
{
#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM
    return UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
#endif
    return NO;
}
```

the `ifdef` block is never entered, and so `return NO;` is always run. **How do I detect if the device is an iPad without using `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()`?**

---

I'm using:

- Xcode 6.3 (6D570)
- iOS 8.2 (12D508) - Compiling with iOS 8.3 compiler
- Deployment: Targeted Device Family: iPhone/iPad
- Mac OS X: Yosemite (10.10.3)
- Mac: MacBook Pro (MacBookPro11,3)

Comment: Right-click `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` and select *Find Definition*.  What does it show?

Comment: @trojanfoe http://imgur.com/SMZjNs7

Comment: That looks OK then.  The `UIKit` documentation shows it's still valid too.  You'll need to show more code I guess (i.e. the code that uses that method).

Comment: @trojanfoe this `isiPad` method is used literally thousands of times in our code. Each time, as far as I can tell, the behavior is as I describe above; it skips to `return NO;`.

Comment: Why do you need the `#ifdef` check? `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` is available in all supported iOS versions.

Comment: OK, how about breakpoints?  (also it's a little expensive to run that method so you should be caching the answer it gives).

Comment: @rmaddy we support back to iOS 5. Is it available there?

Comment: @trojanfoe breakpoints are how I know that it's skipping to `return NO;`; I set a breakpoint on the `#ifdef` line, and it only breaks on the `return NO;` line.

Comment: It was added in 3.2 but now I see the docs in iOS 8.3 suggest not using it. Use the `UIDevice` method directly.

Comment: @rmaddy even so, should `#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` not be `true`?

Comment: Actually the docs say "Available in iOS 8.3 and later", but the docs for `userInterfaceIdiom` say "Available in iOS 3.2 and later.".  I would use `userInterfaceIdiom` as directed by Apple.

Comment: @trojanfoe It's weird because I've been using `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` since iOS 3.2. They must have refactored something in 8.3 and it makes the docs misleading.

Comment: I blame Swift; they probably added a new, more semantic way to check the device for Swift and that might've broken the old way in Objective C.

Comment: When I use the `#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` in iPad, it's always returning 0. But when I use `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` itself, it's returning the correct one, which is 1. Do you know why this happened? :(

Comment: @KarenAnne That's my question! See the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `8.2` `UserInterfaceIdiom()` is

```
#define UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] ? [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] : UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
```

In `8.3` `UserInterfaceIdiom()` is

```
static inline UIUserInterfaceIdiom UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() {
    return ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)] ?
            [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] :
            UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone);
}
```

So `#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` is always false in `8.3`

Note that the header says

> The UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() function is provided for use when
>   deploying to a version of the iOS less than 3.2. If the earliest
>   version of iPhone/iOS that you will be deploying for is 3.2 or
>   greater, you may use -[UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom] directly.

So suggest you refactor to

```
+ (BOOL) isiPad
{
    static BOOL isIPad = NO;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        isIPad = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad;
    });
    return isIPad;
}
```

Comment: and those 4 lines of code will only be run once, yes?

Comment: yes , thats what the dispatch_once function achieves :-)

Comment: Alright. Would it also work to use something like `#define _isiPad [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` and then just return `_isiPad`?

Comment: There is no requirement to calculate this value just once. Its just cheaper to do it only once as iPads don't generally become iPhones midway through the runtime. So yes, `#define` if it suits your purpose. The quoted docs tell you the exact truth. Cmd-Click `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` in Xcode to take you to the header if you wish to read for yourself.

Comment: Hi @WarrenBurton, can you explain why `#ifdef UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` would not work in 8.3? Thanks. I can't understand. :(

Comment: Because presumably to make this work with Swift it's become an inline function.  The answer to the query you make with `#ifdef` "is it defined as a C preprocessor macro", is no.