# Change Row Height size of Table View between iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, row

I know thinks about size class, but here I don't know how to do, on my menu I wan't to have a bigger row height size on iPad than iPhone.

Here I can set the row height:

[image]

But I don't see how to use size class here to have a different height between different devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If doing it in the code is an option, you could do something like this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    tableView.rowHeight = 100;
}
else {
    tableView.rowHeight = 44;
}
```

it should work on iOS 3.2 and above, so basically anything you can realistically target.

Comment: As per my info this method is available in ios 3.2 and above.. (please confirm again) @ishaq

Comment: @FayzaNawaz you are talking about `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM` macro, `userInterfaceIdiom` method is different from that. please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608613/how-can-i-detect-if-device-is-an-ipad-in-ios-8-3

Comment: i'm checking the documentation and have found this in UIKit->UIDevice:


@available(iOS 3.2, *)
public var userInterfaceIdiom: UIUserInterfaceIdion {get}

P.S. i'm working in swift and my app supports iOS 7.1+. I'm using this without any issue (and i know it's not a function but works for the same thing)

Comment: I stand corrected :-) have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Can we detect iphone 4 ... to 6 ?

Comment: there isn't an out of the box method to do it, you'll need to check screen size. details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices , but if you are going there, it would be much better to use size classes instead of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift Use:

```
if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad){
            return 500
        }
        else {
            return 200
        }
```